# SAS looping through SPECIFIC columns

Tags: loops, sas, finance

I'm trying to do a loop for a specific set of columns in my table, and not all of them.
Is there a ways to call certain columns in SAS?
example:
For columns 12 to 30
if value is missing then value=0

I appreciate any help or suggestion ! :)

Comment: By "column" do you mean variables?  You reference variables by their name, not the order they appear in the dataset.  Please provide example input and output.

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/05/29/6-easy-ways-to-specify-a-list-of-variables-in-sas.html plus an array is what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Array + short cut list to reference variables. You need to specify the first and last variable in that list.

```
data want;
set have;
 array vals(*) var12 -- var30;

  do i=1 to dim(vals);
      if missing(vals(i)) then vals(i) = 0;
  end;

run;
```

You may also be able to use PROC STDIZE depending on exactly how your data is structured.